# Get textbox that causes FormatException

Tags: c#, winforms

i have this code:

```
try 
{
    n1 = Convert.ToSingle(textBoxN1.Text); 
    n2 = Convert.ToSingle(textBoxN2.Text);
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
    MessageBoxShow("...");
}
```

is it possible to let the messagebox show which textBox causes the FormatException?

Edit: 
Unfortunately, i have to do it with FormatException, because its part of a homework, where we are forced to use FormatException.

Comment: log e.ToString() and you will find your answer

Comment: But I really need to ask you. Why on earth you want to use an exception to get at this faulty textbox when you can simply avoid it with the proper TryParse instead of Convert?

Comment: @Steve i'm learning c# and this is part of my homework and i have to do it this way :/

Comment: You should use the `TryParse` methods. However, if you really wanted to know what caused the exception in a catch you _could_ also use them for that: `TextBox errorTxt = new []{ textBoxN1,textBoxN2 }.First(txt => !float.TryParse(txt.Text, out float f));`

Comment: And you are doing it in a wrong way. You should avoid raising an exception when there is an easy way to avoid it. They have a very strong impact on performances. See the answer below from [Dmitry Bychenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko)

Comment: @Steve: i guess performance is the worst argument for using `TryParse` instead of  `try{}catch{}`, especially in this case where there is user interaction. He wouldn't notice if the MessageBox opens 
 a millisecond sooner or later.

Comment: @Steve unfortunately, we have to do it with FormatException. I would prefer it the way Dmitry Bychenko does it, but for this homework we are forced to use the FormatException thing.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest putting `float.TryParse` in the `if`:

```
if (!float.TryParse(textBoxN1.Text, out n1))
  MessageBoxShow("textBoxN1 has incorrect value");
else if (!float.TryParse(textBoxN2.Text, out n2))
  MessageBoxShow("textBoxN2 has incorrect value");
else {
  // Both textboxes are correct; n1 and n2 are parsed values
}
```

**Edit:** If you *have to* use `FormatException` let's try to do in the most comfortable way: let's *extract a method*:

```
private static bool TextBoxToSingle(Control control, string message, out float result) {
  float result = float.NaN;

  try {
    result = Convert.ToSingle(control.Text);

    return true;
  }
  catch (FormatException) { // we don't want "e" here
    MessageBoxShow(message);

    return false; 
  }  
}

...

if (TextBoxToSingle(textBoxN1.Text, "textBoxN1 has incorrect value", out n1) && 
    TextBoxToSingle(textBoxN2.Text, "textBoxN2 has incorrect value", out n2)) {
  // Both textboxes are correct; n1 and n2 are parsed values
}
```

Comment: you could use `$"{control.Name} has incorrect value"` and construct the message directly in the method

Comment: @Mong Zhu: technically yes, but I put `"textBoxN1 has incorrect value"` just as an *example*; the real message will be, I guess, something like `"The size of the room must be a floating point value"`

Comment: granted. Well thought.

Answer (score 1):

You can show all the Stack Trace on your `MessageBox` with `e.ToString()`. This string will display which line of code causes the exception. Try:

```
catch (FormatException e)
{
    MessageBoxShow(e.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use the `try...catch` approach like you commented(homework), then you either have to use two consecutive `try...catch` and you know for sure which failed, or use this:

```
float n1 = Single.NaN; // or a different default value
float n2 = Single.NaN; // or a different default value

try
{
    n1 = Convert.ToSingle(textBoxN1.Text);
    n2 = Convert.ToSingle(textBoxN2.Text);
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
    TextBox errorBox = n1 == Single.NaN ? textBoxN1 : textBoxN2;
    MessageBoxShow("This TextBox caused a FormatException: " + errorBox.Name);
}
```